# Module installed but Python cannot find it

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, flask-script, pipenv-install

I am using VS Code running Python 3.9 I have set up a virtual environment using pipenv shell and I installed flask-script as displayed here in my pipfile:

```
   [packages]
   flask = "*"
   sqlalchemy = "*"
   flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
   flask-script = "*"
   flask-migrate = "*"
```

Still the import at the top of the Python file shows yellow underline and:
Import "flask_script" could not be resolved Pylance report MissingImports

and if you try and run it it says:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_script'

So how does it work please? This happens with other modules now and again too. How are you supposed to install a module?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to select the correct python interpreter for the dependencies to be found.

[image]

Make sure it's the one for your virtual environment (You should see the parentheses as here in the screenshot, you can click there and select the correct one).

Comment: Great thank you I did not know about this. This solved it.